# What's the Big-O of a sum of choose functions?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I have an algorithm containing a loop that does $O(n)$ work each iteration.
This loop runs $\sum \limits_{i=1}^d {l \choose i}$ times.

This expands to $\sum \limits_{i=1}^d {\frac{l!}{i!(l-i)!}}$, which can be rewritten as $l! \sum \limits_{i=1}^d {\frac{1}{i!(l-i)!}}$

My intuition tells me that the value of the summation will be insignificant compared to the factor $l!$, especially because $l$ is generally much bigger than $d$ in this particular algorithm.

Firstly, is my intuition correct? If so, is it generally acceptable to ignore a variable such as $d$ in stating the time complexity? In this case I believe that would make the running time $O(l!n)$, right?

Secondly, if I were to include $d$ in the big-O notation, what would it look like? In other words, what is the big-O of the summation?

Comment: If $l$ is much bigger than $d$ then you can probably assume $d<l/2$. In this case each $l\choose i$ in the sum is at most ${l\choose d}=O(l^d/d!)$.

Comment: The loop runs a constant (in $n$) number of times. Each iteration does $O(n)$ work. The total amount of work is still $O(n)$, because the number of iterations is constant. Are you sure this is the question you wanted to ask?